# not resulting in redraw when called from viewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a subview with various methods that update my data and then call  [self setNeedsDisplay]; to invoke the drawRect to update the view.

If I call one of these methods from the viewController, the data gets updated but the drawRect is not called.

The subView is added as a property of the viewController:
`@property (nonatomic,retain) MyView *myView;`

and initiated in the viewController:

```
@synthesize myView;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myView = [[MyView  alloc] init]; 

    }
```

I call a method on myView later in the viewController with `[myView exampleMethod];`

How can I make sure methods called from the viewController redraw the subView?

Comment: When is the view of myView is added as a subview of the view controller's view? You seem not to load the view from Nib as you are allocating in viewDidLoad. Then you should add its view as a subview for the view chain to work properly?

Comment: this was the problem. I had a confusing layout and the view referred to was not the one being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't you have to call

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

:)

The default view in a view controller is called just "view" if you want to make your own, you have to add it to that or exchange the view with that, like this:

```
self.view = myView;
//or
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```